# Generating all possible unique combinations of dataset with two variables

Tags: r, combinatorics

I am fairly new to R and I have been reading all related topics but still I don't manage to solve my rather simple problem.

I have a dataset with 5 cases for two variables (X,Y), for instance:

```
  X |  Y
--------
100 | 12
112 | 14
140 | 21    
190 | 20
 89 |  7
```

Now I want to replicate this dataset with all possible unique combinations of both variables. If I'm not mistaken there would be !5 = 120 different sets.

Now, I have been trying to do this with the 'sample' command. By keeping E constant and then sampling F, I can get a new dataset with different combinations of E and F. The problem of course is that this doesn't return all possible combinations. If I would do this 120 times, I would not get unique datasets.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Best regards,
P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`permn` from the package `combinat` will give you all the permutations of a vector.  Then a simple loop will get you all your datasets:

```
x <- c(100, 112, 140, 190, 89)
y <- c(12, 14, 21, 20, 7)
z <- permn(x)
for(i in 1:length(z)){
  z[[i]] <- rbind(z[[i]], y)
}
```